# After Upgrade from Magento 1.7 to 1.9 OnePage Checkout Sidebar Not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

After Upgrade from `Magento 1.7` to `1.9` OnePage Checkout Sidebar Not working properly.

During the first step it is appearing. When we click a button the sidebar disappears. 
`<div>` tag having the id `checkout-progress-wrapper` is showing empty.

How to resolve this?

Comment: this issue is resolve or not?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in your `app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/Theme/js/opcheckout.js`

Just rename your `opcheckout.js` and check if it is working now.

Comment: Now it is showing. But the side bar contents not updating.. For example after shipping address step it is not updating with the address.......

Comment: please rename below 
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/Theme/template/
+chekout
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/Theme/layout/
+chekout.xml